# Blackjack implementation - Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, playing-cards

I have inspired from the recent blackjack question here and decide to code for simple blackjack console application
Please review and let me know What can improve on the code?

### Rules for the application:

1. There's a single dealer and a player
2. Initially both get two cards
3. Number `2` to `9` cards have their numerical value that is counted as their score, Face cards have value of `10`, Ace's value changes based on the current score
4. Then Player asks dealer to `hit`, as long as Player's score is less than `17`
5. When Player reaches `17` or more then they no longer go for `hit`
6. Dealer starts their turn, they go for hit as long as Dealer's score is less than `17`
7. After both are done with their turns, Outcome would be decided
8. Every action has system out, output will be similar to this

> Task :GamePlay.main()
> Dealer got 4♣    score: 4    status: HIT
> Dealer got K♦︎   score: 14   status: HIT
> Player got A♦︎   score: 11   status: HIT
> Player got J♥    score: 21   status: BLACKJACK
> Dealer got 10♠   score: 24   status: BUST
> Dealer Bust, Player Wins

#### class Card

```
public class Card {
    private Suit suit;
    private Type type;

    public Card(Suit suit, Type type) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getType().toString() +  this.getSuit().toString();
    }
}
```

#### enum Suit

```
public enum Suit {
    SPADE('♠'), DIAMOND('♦︎'), CLUB('♣'), HEART('♥');

    private final char symbol;
    Suit(char symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(this.symbol);
    }
}
```

#### enum Type

Type enum constructor takes two parameters, their default value and symbol to represent on output, also the enum has `getDefaultValue` method

`Ace` has overriden the method. since it has it's own implementation

```
import static blackjack.GamePlay.ACE_MAX_VALUE;

public enum Type {
    
    TWO(2, "2"), THREE(3, "3"), FOUR(4, "4"), FIVE(5, "5"),
    SIX(6, "6"), SEVEN(7, "7"), EIGHT(8, "8"), NINE(9, "9"),
    TEN(10, "10"),
    ACE(ACE_MAX_VALUE, "A") {
        @Override
        public int getDefaultValue(int totalValue) {
            if (totalValue + ACE_MAX_VALUE > 21) {
                return 1;
            }
            return ACE_MAX_VALUE;
        }
    },
    JACK(10, "J"), QUEEN(10, "Q"), KING(10, "K");
    
    private int defaultValue;
    private String symbol;

    Type(int defaultValue, String symbol) {
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public int getDefaultValue(int totalValue) {
        return this.defaultValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.symbol;
    }
}
```

#### class Deck

Deck has list of all 52 `Card`s and loads them into the list on constructor, it has `getACard` method which removes a card from random index and return a `Card` object for dealer to draw

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck {
    private List<Card> cards;

    public Deck() {
        this.cards = new ArrayList<>();
        loadCards();
    }

    private void loadCards() {
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
            for (Type type : Type.values()) {
                this.cards.add(new Card(suit, type));
            }
        }
    }

    public Card getACard() {
        int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(this.cards.size());
        return this.cards.remove(randomIndex);
    }
}
```

#### class Dealer

`Dealer` has the `Deck`, on constructor it draws two cards and adds to their list of cards
and updates their score and status.

It has `hit` method which draws a `Card` from the `Deck` and returns. based on the value of the `card` their score and status is updated.
`play` method does the orchestration also prints the state of the `Dealer`

`canHit` method checks the status of the Dealer returns `true` if they're in `HIT` status

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static blackjack.GamePlay.*;

public class Dealer {
    private Deck deck;
    private List<Card> cards;
    private int score;
    private Status status;

    public Dealer(Deck deck) {
        this.cards = new ArrayList<>();
        this.deck = deck;
        for (int i = 0; i < INITIAL_CARDS_COUNT; i++) {
            play();
        }
    }

    public Card hit() {
        return this.deck.getACard();
    }

    public void play() {
        Card card = hit();
        this.score += card.getType().getDefaultValue(this.score);
        this.cards.add(card);
        this.status = Status.getStatus(this.score);
        System.out.printf("Dealer got %s \t score: %d \t status: %s \n", card, this.score,this.status.toString());
    }

    public boolean canHit() {
        return this.status.equals(Status.HIT);
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
}
```

#### class Player

`Player` has the `Dealer`, on constructor it draws two cards and adds to their list of cards and updates their score and status.

It has `hit` method which draws a `Card` from the `Dealer` and returns. based on the value of the `card` their score and status is updated.
`play` method does the orchestration also prints the state of the `Player`

`canHit` method checks the status of the Dealer returns `true` if they're in `HIT` status

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static blackjack.GamePlay.INITIAL_CARDS_COUNT;
import static blackjack.Status.HIT;

public class Player {
    private List<Card> cards;
    private Dealer dealer;
    private int score;
    private Status status;

    public Player(Dealer dealer) {
        this.cards = new ArrayList<>();
        this.dealer = dealer;
        for (int i = 0; i < INITIAL_CARDS_COUNT; i++) {
            play();
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        Card card = this.dealer.hit();
        this.score += card.getType().getDefaultValue(this.score);
        this.cards.add(card);
        this.status = Status.getStatus(this.score);
        System.out.printf("Player got %s \t score: %d \t status: %s \n", card, this.score,this.status.toString());
    }

    public boolean canHit() {
        return this.status.equals(HIT);
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
}
```

#### enum Status

Status enum has constructor takes two params `min` and `max`, this decides which `Status` any score fall in

`getStatus` method takes score and return `Status` based on the score

```
public enum Status {
    HIT(0, 16), STAND(17, 20), BLACKJACK(21, 21), BUST(22, 100);

    private int min;
    private int max;

    Status(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public static Status getStatus(int score) {
        Status[] statuses = Status.values();
        for (Status status : statuses) {
            if (status.min <= score && status.max >= score) {
                return status;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### class GamePlay

This is orchestrator for the application creates All objects and decides the outcome of the game

```
public class GamePlay {

    public static final int INITIAL_CARDS_COUNT = 2;
    public static final int ACE_MAX_VALUE = 11;

    public static String getOutcome(Player player, Dealer dealer) {
        if (player.getStatus().equals(Status.BUST)) {
            return "Player Bust, Dealer Wins";
        } else if (player.getScore() == dealer.getScore()) {
            return "Tie";
        } else if (dealer.getStatus().equals(Status.BUST)) {
            return "Dealer Bust, Player Wins";
        } else if (player.getScore() > dealer.getScore()) {
            return "Player Wins";
        }
        return "Dealer Wins";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        Dealer dealer = new Dealer(deck);
        Player player = new Player(dealer);
        while (player.canHit()) {
            player.play();
        }
        while (dealer.canHit()) {
            dealer.play();
        }
        System.out.println(getOutcome(player, dealer));

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the score of ACE, THREE, KING in your program? Does that match the Blackjack rules? THREE, KING, ACE should give the same result, shouldn't it? How would you write an automated test (e.g. JUnit) for that?

Comment: Yes that won't work out in the code, i will have to fix that @Ralf Kleberhoff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code looks pretty decent.  I can look at it and follow what is going on without too much difficulty.  Here are a few things for your consideration.  Note that some are aesthetic, and some are not super important for a small program but could be for a larger program, and there are a couple of questions to think about different ways you could have done things.

---

1. `enum Type`

For the `Type`s, `ACE` is right after `TEN` and before `JACK`, `QUEEN`, and `KING`.  Those last four all have 10 as a value, so it would probably be better to put `ACE` *after* them.  (General rule of organization: Similar things go together.)

`ACE_MAX_VALUE` is defined over in the `GamePlay` class.  You may have some aesthetic for putting it there, but it is only used in the `Type` enum.  Also this creates a circular dependency through `GamePlay`, `Deck`, `Type`, `GamePlay`, etc.  Consider moving it into `Type`, though you may have to use an ugly [static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23609178).  (Note: You can see dependencies in a program like Stan4J or Structure101.)

The word `Type` is extremely generic.  How about something a little more descriptive, perhaps `FaceValue`?

---

2. `Dealer` and `Player`

Is it necessary for the `Player` to have a reference to the `Dealer` just so the `Dealer` can get a card for the `Player`?  I realize there is text in the "Rules" at the top saying that the `Player` gets the card from the `Dealer`, but it may not be necessary if you let them both know about the `Deck`.

The `GamePlay` class has the logic for `while (player.canHit()) player.play();`.  Could `Player` simply have a `playAll()` method?

These two classes are nearly identical, so there is duplicate code.  Could they be the same?  If so, you could move the definition of the `INITIAL_CARDS_COUNT` constant into that class.  (General principle: DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself)

---

3. `Deck`

The `Deck` is creating a `new Random()` for each draw.  You could create one, and save it as part of the class state.  This is probably not important for such a small program.

Something else that may not be important in this example, when you remove a card from the `List`, all other cards, all other cards from the removed index to the end of the list have to be moved down.  Mind you, your code is clear and correct as is, however it is just a little inefficient.  You could read the item at the index, move the last item to the current item, and then remove the final item from the `List` so nothing gets moved down.

The method name `getACard()` might read better as `drawCard()`.

---

4. Have you considered unit testing?

How would you unit test this thing?  How many unit tests would you need?  Perhaps you could have an alternate constructor for `Deck` that takes in a seed for the `Random` to get a predictable order.

How would the program have come out different if you had coded it with TDD (or even BDD)?  Just in case you (or other readers) don't know, JUnit is the most common Java TDD framework, and Cucumber for Java is the most common Java BDD framework.

---

5. `enum Status`

The game logic only depends on `canHit`, so you really only need two `Status`es - one for playing and one for done.  Or perhaps `play()` can return a boolean indicating whether it is done?  Perhaps there should be a separate `enum Result`?

---

Nice work.  I hope this gives you some ideas to "plus" it.

Comment: Your suggestions are helpful, very much appreciated 
`These two classes are nearly identical, so there is duplicate code. Could they be the same`, how do you suggest i do that `inheritance`?

Comment: You could potentially avoid inheritance completely by having only one class.  If you just have a `Player` class, you can say `Player player1 = new Player("Player", deck); Player dealer = new Player("Dealer", deck);`.  The only thing that needs to differ is the name, so pass that into the constructor.  Interfaces or abstract classes would be overkill.  A single class would be the simplest thing you could do.

Answer (score 2):

## Testing

- There is none.

## Type

- I would expect this class to be named `Rank`, which is what this
  concept is called by card players.
- The value of a card doesn't belong in this class, because the value of cards varies by game. This implementation restricts the reusability of a Type to only blackjack.

## Deck

- This implementation is confusing. A deck of cards is shuffled, and
  then during the course of play the top card is drawn. That would be
  just as easy to implement and would make more sense to people
  familiar with card games than pulling a random card from somewhere in
  the deck.
- When working with `Random`, it's important to pass in (inject) an
  instance rather than instantiating it inside the class. The reason is
  repeatable unit tests - if the test can't control the random seed,
  deck behavior can't be predicted.

## Dealer

- This class is overloaded .. it's doing two things. It is both a player of the game and a distributor of cards.  The `Player` class, should be used to model the "player of the game" aspect. This will also cut down on repeated code.
- The computation of hand value ("score") does not work correctly when the first card drawn is an ace. Its value will always be 11. If the first card is not an ace but the second card is, its value will always be 11.

## Player

- Player should be an interface, with perhaps an abstract class holding supporting code. A `ComputerDealer` might be one type of player. A `ConsoleHuman` might be another type, where information is written to and read from the console to allow actual play. Players should have a hand of cards, and should respond to a method call by reporting how they act (hit or stand). If they hit, the controller should give the player another card and then check the value of their hand to see if they've busted.
- As it is, there are two robots with the same algorithm "playing" each other, but they're in different classes with duplicated code.

## Status

- This isn't status, this is the logic for determining how a computer player should behave, loosely corresponding to the perceived value of their hand. A more descriptive name would be better. But really, this logic belongs in `ComputerDealer`. And to hold to casino rules, it should address soft vs. hard 17s.

## GamePlay

- `ACE_MAX_VALUE` belongs in the new class that will compute hand value.
- The rules on how to play blackjack, which are scattered through the other classes, should be pulled into this class.

Comment: Suggestions are helpful, Really appreciated.